# Why will this cookie not change it's value when assigned?

Tags: javascript, cookies

So, I've been learning about cookies. I've been trying to remove a certain product hash that I use in a shop cart from a cookie with the name 'ItemCart'. 
The cookie is formatted in this way:

ItemCart=productHash;

However, when I try to remove it, the cookie seems like it is rejecting the change somehow.  Here is the code in js:

```
var cookieRemoval = document.cookie.replace("ItemCart="+this.getAttribute("data-hash")+"; ", "");
document.cookie = cookieRemoval;
console.log(document.cookie + " should now be " + cookieRemoval);
```

Where data-hash is a data attribute of the current element of the page being clicked on to remove the hash in cookie.

Here is the output in the console (avoiding php session garbage):

```
ItemCart=EyG439ktw8hT; should now be
```

This means that the replace function is done correctly, but the cookie won't change.

Is this somehow related to not directly dealing with the expiry date?

I don't really understand what's going on here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.cookie` doesn't work that way. It's not a real variable, more like [special syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.cookie).

To unset a cookie, do

```
document.cookie = "ItemCart=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;"
```

which is, admittedly, pretty strange.

Comment: So, I am able to leave the name of the cookie present in the string, but remove the content? And should I have to worry about the expiry date either? Thanks.

Comment: No, the syntax `document.cookie = x` does *not* mean "set document.cookie to x"; it means "set a new cookie based off description x". In fact, the line I posted will do precisely one thing: expire ItemCart. Other cookies are not affected. As I mentioned, this is pretty strange and takes some getting used to.

Comment: Ok I understand. It is not a normal variable as I had been treating it. Thanks